# Logic design in jmeter - pass errors in test flow chain

Tags: jmeter

please advice what has to be the good design and implementation of the following scenario I'm faced with.

**Design**

```
Sampler 1 (prerequisite)
Sampler 2 (prerequisite)
Sampler 3 (actual test)
```

**Execution**

```
    Sampler 1 failed with error
    Sampler 2 not executed 
    Sampler 3 not executed but marked as failed with Sampler 1 error or executed but result data replaced with error from Sampler 1
```

Note: Prerequisite samplers are excluded from end result report(already found solution for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design your test as follows:

- Sampler 1

  - [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the following code:

    ```
    if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
        vars.putObject('sampler1Result', prev)
    }
    ```
- [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) with the following condition: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`

  - Sampler 2
- Sampler 3

  - JSR223 PostProcessor with the following code:

    ```
    if (vars.getObject('sampler1Result') != null) {
        def sampler1Result = vars.getObject('sampler1Result')
        prev.setSuccessful(sampler1Result.isSuccessful())
         prev.setResponseCode(sampler1Result.getResponseCode())
         prev.setResponseMessage(sampler1Result.getResponseMessage())
         prev.setResponseData(sampler1Result.getResponseData())
    }
    ```

Where:

- `vars` - is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
- `prev` - is a shorthand for [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) class instance

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, seems to be work for me. Can you please advice how to add also failed sampler name with error returned in the Sampler 3 response

Comment: `sampler1Result.getSampleLabel()` should return the name of the `Sampler1`. See [SampleResult JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSampleLabel--) in particular and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) in general for more details.

Comment: Already did, but not sure how to merge both in prev.setResponseData. I'm getting this on
prev.setResponseData(sampler1Result.getSampleLabel() + sampler1Result.getResponseData()) - jp@gc - Dummy Sampler[83, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 114, 32, 49, 32, 114, 101, 115, 112, 111, 110, 115, 101]

Comment: Had to use getResponseDataAsString instead of getResponseData